# Error: Type 'Classname' does not provide a call operator

Tags: c++

Working on a program involving matrices and hit with an error involving `Multiply` and `Transpose` methods. I'm not sure how to proceed

```
//Header file
class Matrix

{
public:
  Matrix();                                  // constructor
  void initIdentity(int n);                  // initialize as an identity matrix of size nxn
  void initFromFile(string fileName);        // read the matrix from a file
  bool isSquare();                           // test whether matrix is square
  int numRows();                             // return number of rows
  int numCols();                             // return number of columns
  double getVal(int row, int col);           // return matrix value at given row/col location (0-indexed based)
  void setVal(int row, int col, double val); // set the matrix value at given row/col location (0-index based)
  Matrix Multiply(Matrix B);                 // post-multiply by B and return resulting matrix
  Matrix Multiply(double A);                 // multiply by a scalar and return resulting matrix
  Matrix Transpose();                        // return transpose of matrix
  vector<double> Diagonal();                 // return a vector containing diagonal elements of the matrix
  void Print();                              // print the matrix to stdout
  void Print(string name);                   // print the matrix to stdout with a name prefix
  Matrix(int row, int col, double val);      // initializing a matrix
  
private:
vector< vector<double> > matrix_;
vector< vector<int> > identMatrix_;
vector<double> innerVec_;
int numRows_;
int numCols_;

};

//Main file
Matrix Matrix::Multiply(double A){
  Matrix ans(numRows_, numCols_, 0.0);
  
  for (int i=0; i< numRows_; i++){
    for (int j=0; j< numCols_; j++){
      ans(i, j) = matrix_[i][j] * A;
    }
  }
  return ans;
}

Matrix Matrix::Transpose(){
  Matrix ans(numRows_, numCols_, 0.0);
    for (int i=0; i<numRows_; i++){
      for (int j=0; j<numCols_; j++){
    ans(i, j) = matrix_[j][i];
      }
    }
  return ans;
}
```

Error:

```
Main.cpp:110:7: error: type 'Matrix' does not provide a call operator
      ans(i, j) = matrix_[i][j] * A;
      ^~~
Main.cpp:120:5: error: type 'Matrix' does not provide a call operator
    ans(i, j) = matrix_[j][i];
    ^~~
```

Comment: I think you wanted `ans.setVal(i,j,matrix_[i][j] * A);` instead of `ans(i, j) = matrix_[i][j] * A;`

Comment: If you want `ans(i, j)` to be meaningful, you need to define an `operator()`. But it looks like you've defined `setVal`, which you should probably use instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments, you have:

```
ans(i, j) = matrix_[i][j] * A;
```

Which is trying to call `operator()` on `ans`. But you haven't defined this operator for this type of object.

You'd either need to define that operator so this code works, or just use the existing `setVal`:

```
ans.setVal(i, j, matrix_[i][j] * A);
```